# Bootbox confirmation box doesn't work after click "update button"

Tags: javascript, php, bootbox

currently I developed a system which included CRUD (Create, Read, Update Delete). My scenario is, the admin needs to update details of some information.

The update is successful but the bootbox has no appeared. Different when I used to logout. The bootbox dialog will popup. The method that I used is the same. Below is my full code

```
  <?php
  $sql = "";
  require_once "../../config/configPDO.php";
  require_once "../../config/check.php";

  if(isset($_POST['update']))
  { 
    $Email = $_POST['Email'];

    // checking empty fields
    if(empty($Email)) { 

      if(empty($Email)) {
        echo "<font color='red'>Fac_Name field is empty.</font><br/>";
      }

    } else {    
      //updating the table
      $sql = "UPDATE staff SET Role_ID = :Role_ID WHERE Email = :Email";
      $query = $conn->prepare($sql);

      $query->bindParam(':Role_ID', $_POST['Role_ID']);;
      $query->bindParam(':Email', $_POST['Email']);
      $query->execute();

      //redirectig to the display page. In our case, it is index.php
      header("Location: ../dashboard/dashboard_super_admin.php");
    }
  }
  ?>
  <?php
  //getting id from url
  $Email = $_GET['Email'];

  //selecting data associated with this particular id
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM staff LEFT JOIN roles on staff.Role_ID = roles.Role_ID WHERE Email = :Email";
  $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $query->execute(array(':Email' => $Email));

  while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
  {
    $Email = $row["Email"];;
    $Fullname = $row["Fullname"];
    $Badge_No = $row["Badge_No"];
    $Fac_ID = $row["Fac_ID"];
    $Role_Desc = $row["Role_Desc"];
    $Role_ID = $row["Role_ID"];
  }
  ?>


  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <body>
    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
      <table class = "table table-bordered">
        <tr>
          <td width="20%"><b>Email</b></td>
          <td width="80%"><?php echo $Email; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="20%"><b>Full Name</b></td>
          <td width="80%"><?php echo $Fullname; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="20%"><b>Factory in Charge</b></td>
          <td width="80%"><?php echo $Fac_ID; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="20%"><b>Role</b></td>
          <td width="80%">
            <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="Role_ID">
              <option value="1" <?php echo $Role_ID == '1'? 'selected': '';?> >Super Admin</option>
              <option value="2" <?php echo $Role_ID == '2'? 'selected': '';?> >Admin</option>
              <option value="3" <?php echo $Role_ID == '3'? 'selected': '';?> >Normal</option>
            </select>
            <input type="hidden" name="Email" value="<?php echo $Email ?>">
          </td>
        </tr> 
      </table><br>
        <div align="center">
          <td><button class ="btn btn-primary btn-block" name="update" value="Update" onclick="update()">Update</button></td>
            </div>
    </form><br>             

  <!-- Bootbox -->
  <script src="../../bootbox/bootbox.all.js"></script>
  <script src="../../bootbox/bootbox.all.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../../bootbox/bootbox.locales.js"></script>
  <script src="../../bootbox/bootbox.locales.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../../bootbox/bootbox.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootbox End -->

  <!--update admin  -->
  <script>
  function update() {
    bootbox.confirm({
    title: "<span style='color: white;'><b>Update</b></span>",
    message: "Do you want to update?",
    buttons: {
        confirm: {
            label: 'Yes',
            className: 'btn btn-primary btn-sm'
        },
        cancel: {
            label: 'No',
            className: 'btn btn-danger btn-sm'
        }
    },
  callback: function (result) {
    if (result === true) {
          location.href = '../../dashboard/dashboard_super_admin.php';
      }else{

      }
    }
      });
  }
</script>
<!-- update admin -->

  </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: Is there happen to be an error logged into the console? I've used bootbox a bit, but it became a unreliable for my needs and I just switched over to using bootstrap's modal. It is a little more work, but it is easier for me to use. Not sure if that'll fit your needs, but I digress. Any errors outputted to the console?

Comment: When I ran your code on bootboxjs.com, it ran fine and it redirected me as it should in your callback. So your script is not the cause of your issues. Make sure your listener is attached when you're clicking your button and that your css is not overriding bootbox. I know I had one issue with css overriding bootbox and making it not appear. Lastly, check your inspector and make sure your php is not affecting the html syntax. Good luck, also if you can't find it. Please reword your question to make it clearer on what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The default type of a `<button>` is `submit`, so clicking on that button is going to trigger a form / page submit. If you want to the user to confirm that submission AND use Bootbox, you have to cancel the form submission, since Bootstrap (and therefore Bootbox) modals [cannot block code execution](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/javascript/#asynchronous-functions-and-transitions).

So, start with this:

```
function update(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    bootbox.confirm({
        title: "<span style='color: white;'><b>Update</b></span>",
        message: "Do you want to update?",
        buttons: {
            confirm: {
                label: 'Yes',
                className: 'btn btn-primary btn-sm'
            },
            cancel: {
                label: 'No',
                className: 'btn btn-danger btn-sm'
            }
        },
        callback: function (result) {
            if (result) {
                location.href = '../../dashboard/dashboard_super_admin.php';
            }else{

            }
        }
    });
}
```

Your callback needs to be updated, as that is a GET request, not a POST. Since you're using Bootstrap, you are also using either jQuery or Zepto (or similar), so you have access to the [$.post](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) function:

```
function update(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    bootbox.confirm({
        title: "<span style='color: white;'><b>Update</b></span>",
        message: "Do you want to update?",
        buttons: {
            confirm: {
                label: 'Yes',
                className: 'btn btn-primary btn-sm'
            },
            cancel: {
                label: 'No',
                className: 'btn btn-danger btn-sm'
            }
        },
        callback: function (result) {
            if (result) {
                let data = $('form').serialize();
                let url = '../../dashboard/dashboard_super_admin.php';

                $.post(url, data)
                    .done(function(response){
                        location.href = url;
                    })
                    .fail(function(){
                        bootbox.alert('Update failed');
                    });
            }else{

            }
        }
    });
}
```

[serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) will encode your form into a format that the post helper understands - the rest should be fairly straightforward.